# Python, как избавиться от перечисления всех вариантов if-else в функции?

Tags: python

Есть скрипт, который запускается с параметрами, код в нем подобен коду, который я привел ниже.
Как правильно сделать так, чтобы я мог задавать параметры одновременно, при этом не перечисляя все
варианты в условиях if-else? Допустим, хочу вызвать main, чтобы вывелось полная фраза Hello my world, при этом не писать if a and b and c: print("Hello my world")

```
def method_a():
    print("Hello")
def method_b():
    print("my")
def method_c():
    print("world!")

def main(a=None,b=None,c=None):
    if a:
        method_a()
    elif b:
        method_b()
    elif c:
        method_b()
        
main(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

Comment: Если условия действительно независимы, то вместо `elif` используйте просто `if` и получите то, что хотите.

Answer (score 4):

Ну, например, можно сделать так:

```
def method_a():
    print("Hello")
def method_b():
    print("my")
def method_c():
    print("world!")
    
def main(a=None,b=None,c=None):
    d = {a:method_a, b:method_b, c:method_c}
    [d[x]() for x in d.keys() if x]
```

теперь для

```
main(a=1, b=2, c=3)
```

получаем

```
Hello
my
world!
```

а для

```
main(b=2, c=3)
```

соответственно

```
my
world!
```

Comment: При a=1, b=1 неправильный вывод будет.

Answer (score 4):

Можно все методы объединить в один словарь, а параметры на входе собрать через `kwargs`. Дальше проверяем вхождение параметров в ключи словаря с функциями, которые по нему вызываем.

```
def method_a():
    print("Hello")
    
def method_b():
    print("my")
    
def method_c():
    print("world!")

def methods(**kwargs):
    funcs = {'a': method_a, 'b': method_b, 'c': method_c}
    for k in kwargs:
        funcs[k]() if kwargs[k] else None
        
methods(a=1, b=1, c=3)
```

Вывод:

```
Hello
my
world!
```